Powershell Write-Host Line Breaks In Different Scripts
I have 2 different scripts with line breaks. One of them won't make line breaks without "`n" at the end of each line. See this example with and without the "`n".

But other scripts work without the "`n" tag.
write-host "
This is a test message

This is 2 lines down.
"

Output:

This is a test message

This is two lines down.


What makes them different where they do or don't need the "`n". They are both .ps1 extensions. And, as you can see, they are at the start of the script. Why do some scripts show the line breaks with the "`n" and others don't need it?

The first one you have double quotes inside double quotes.  So in the "`n" the following the backtick is interpreted as a line continuation instead of control n.

@jdweng I understand what they are for. I am trying to find out some scripts require the single line string to make line breaks and others don't.

In multiline strings, literal newlines are normally always respected, as in your second script. I cannot reproduce your symptom, and I'm also baffled that no initial newline is printed before each Write-Host call's output in your first script. Does your first script contain hidden control characters or is unusual in some other respect? Also, you seem to be using the ISE, so let me offer the standard advice in the next comment:

As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is no longer actively developed and there are reasons not to use it (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is Visual Studio Code with its PowerShell extension.

@mklement0 so this sounds like an issue with the Powershell version on maybe Win10/Win11.

I don't think it's an issue with PowerShell itself, I suspect it's the specific content of your first .ps1 files, but without being able to inspect it, I cannot tell. Pasting the contents here may not preserve all characters. You can inspect it yourself with Format-Hex or via the Debug-String function, available as an MIT-licensed Gist, as demonstrated in the bottom section of this answer.

Maybe your editor is wrapping the line, but there's no line break there.

Your 1st example doesnt "need" the quotes or escaped newlines on line 2&3. It just so happens munging together multiple strings is syntactically valid for Write-Host.

Line 3 is outside the double quotes and a different color.  You're pressing play in the ISE?

Is that the whole script?  There's at least one more write-host 'press enter to being' missing at the bottom.  Powershell 5.1?

write-host hi \`` and then on line 2 there` would be one line of output, the backquote being a line continue character.

Going off what @mklement0 said about not being able to use PWSH7 in the IDE. It Can Be done. See Here https://blog.ironmansoftware.com/using-powershell-7-in-the-windows-powershell-ise/ I've tested it and it works but there is some funkyness. Like output headers get messed up for one. Visual Studio   Code is the way to go. It's easy to switch back and forth between 5 and 7. You just have to install all the modules for each environment separately. Some will work between both but I like to keep it clean.

@MattWilliamson: The linked blog post is interesting as an academic exercise, but not suited to real-world use, not least due to the limitations of the ISE itself (different character encoding, no support for interactive console applications, stderr output as PowerShell errors, ...), but specifically because the use of an out-of-process runspace involves serialization/deserialization, which is not only slow but results in loss of type fidelity. Indeed, Visual Studio Code is the way forward.

The second script is one string (characters between double quotes) and the returns are part of the string at the end of each line.  The first script you are combining multiple strings and the `n is not inside any pair of double quotes.  So the back tick is being interpreted as a Line Continuation instead of a return.

@jdweng: A backtick only ever functions as the line continuation character if it is the very last character on a line, so your explanation is incorrect.

@mklement0 : Are you sure.  The results show that the return is being ignored.  Why is the return being ignored?  I think I'm right and you are wrong.  Or the system need both the return and linefeed : rn

I'm making a similar guess, although we can't tell by the example.

@jdweng: Yes, I'm sure with respect to the statement I made (if what you claim were true, then a literal n would print on the next line). And it's easy for you to verify that fact. Doing so is more productive than engaging in fruitless who's-right-and-who's-wrong debates. There's no explanation for the OP's symptom at this point; my previous comment about examining the exact content of the script file may help solve the mystery.

@mklement0 So you are correct that the 'n makes new lines. But that still doesn't explain why the bottom image works without the `n

@JukEboX, it's the opposite: the bottom image is the expected behavior. I have no explanation for the top image. As noted, I suggest inspecting the script file for hidden control characters.

Hey, we don't post images of code or output here.

So after working with some friends here we found that issue seems to be the way that ISE reads the file when it is made. If you make a new .ps1 file on ISE it does not notice the script items like Write-Host or functions as a full block of function. This would be denoted by the collapse (+/-) symbol next to that line of code. This means you need to add the `n code to end of each Write-Host line break for it to identify it.
Example: This is a .ps1 file started and made in ISE:

Now the easiest way to fix this is to take the code and start it over in a Notepad file. Copy your code into a new file on Notepad and then save it as a .ps1. When you do this your Write-Host line breaks will not require the `n as it is being read by ISE correctly.
Example: This is a .ps1 file started and made in Notepad:

I am not sure why there is a there is an error with ISE reading .ps1 files when made in ISE and reading line breaks with Write-Host. It may  have something to do with no longer being supported. Suggestion would be to move over to VS code with Powershell and code with that. Very strange issue but glad I understand now.

ISE works for me.  I assume there's a closing quote at the end.

I also cannot reproduce this: The icon for collapsing the statement appears right away when I type or paste a Write-Host statement with a multiline string into a new document in the ISE, and running the script (even before saving it) behaves as expected. This is on Windows 11, with ISE file version 10.0.22621.1

which version of ISE are you using? I still can't reproduce

Consider the following 2 lines of code:
Write-Host "im`na`nmultiline`nstring"

and
Write-Host "im
a
multiline
string"

They both produce the same output:
im
a
multiline
string

The first is using the escape sequence `n embedded into a single line string. The 2nd is a string that already includes literal newline characters.

For completeness, same can be achieved with a here string(/heredoc) type syntax:
Write-Host @"
I'm
a
heredoc
multiline
string
"@


I understand what they are for. I am trying to find out some scripts require the single line string to make line breaks and others don't.

A string is 0 or more characters between pairs of " double quotes " - your first example i count 6 double quotes - so your not dealing with a single string. Powershell is very relaxed in its syntax, so this isnt treated as an error, its perfectly valid to concatenate multiple strings together - thats the difference. Another syntax that might be useful to know is the herestring - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/

+1 for the general information (the OP's symptoms are a mystery); a few quibbles: it is the newline format of the enclosing file that
determines the newline format of multiline string literals, so it may be \nor`r`n. PowerShell's syntax is only relaxed in [_argument mode_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode), and even there string concatenation doesn't always work as you'd expect; e.g. "foo"`n"bar", when passed to a _command_, is _two_ arguments, "foo"and`n"bar", a fact obscured by Write-Host`.

@MisterSmith I have tried the splat method and this does not work. It makes all the text on one line still.

The only way I can reproduce it is to use backquotes.  The output ends up on one line.
write-host `
hi `
there

Output:
hi there

